# Caption package is adding vertical spacing to my document

Tags: vertical-alignment, captions

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{background}{rgb}{1,0.62502,0}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true,
  urlcolor     = blue,
  linkcolor    = blue,   
  citecolor    = red    
  }
 \usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{6.5cm}
\noindent
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fcolorbox{background}{background}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
\lipsum[4]
%\fcolorbox{frame color}{box background color}{text}
\end{minipage}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical misalignment between the text in the minipage and the text around it is very slight, but noticeable (see esp the bottom of the snip and how the bottom of the p is cut off in the minipage but largely visible in the adjacent line in the wrapped text). When I remove \usepackage{caption} from the above code, the text in the minipage becomes aligned with the wrapping text:

[image]

How can I stop the caption package from producing this vertical misalignment?

Comment: If you use a bottom aligned `minipage` (`[b]`) or center `[c]` aligned, then with and without the `caption` package produce the same result.

Comment: I tried changing to [b] and [c] and the quite slight vertical misalignment remained.

Comment: The package `caption` hasn't anything with space around your wrap figure. If you omit minipage position option `[t]` your wrapfigure is nice centered. If you like to have less vertical space around it, you need manually set its height, for example: `\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{l}{6.5cm}
\vskip-0.5\baselineskip˙`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your behavior with your provided MWE, when the `[b]` or `[c]` option of `minipage` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interaction between the `caption` package and `hyperref`.  You can discover this by using `\showoutput` and examining the `.log` file, where you will see the following material is inserted

```
........\glue -6.02773
........\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
........\penalty 10000
........\glue -6.0
........\glue 0.0
........\pdfdest name{figure.caption.1} xyz
........\penalty 10000
........\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
........\penalty 10000
........\glue 6.0
........\glue 0.0
........\glue(\parskip) 0.0
........\glue(\parskip) 0.0
```

This looks like the glues ought to cancel out, but apparently they do not.
Setting the option `hypcap=false` for the `caption` package removes the extra vertical space.  The `hyperref` anchor, then gets placed at any caption you add instead of the beginning of the environment.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{background}{rgb}{1,0.62502,0}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true,
  urlcolor     = blue,
  linkcolor    = blue,
  citecolor    = red,
  }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{6.5cm}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\fcolorbox{background}{background}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}}%
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Incidentally, I have commented out (using `%`) a couple of line endings in your set-up, that introdced some horizontal spacing, that may or may not have been desired.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also see you added a % to remove horizontal spacing, which I was also curious about how that got into my environment. Can you explain why the % is needed? I do not see anything that comes after the % and so I do not understand how it is removing horizontal spacing.

Comment: Glad this helped.  Ends of lines in many circumstances count as a space.  There is some explanation and references in the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/15925